# Dropdown Select issue on Edit Command in Grid

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid, edit, dropdownbox

I have a grid . I am filling my grid . In that i have edit button . when i click edit all the values in the grid should be selected in my otherpage DROPDOWN.

**ddlconfemail.SelectedItem.Text = item["scoreconfirmeemail"].Text;**

If i use this i get duplication meaning my initial item index of zero which is  (--please select--)get replaced by this item .

but if i use this

ddlconfemail.selectedvalue = item["scoreconfirmeemailid"].Text;

This works perfect .

The  thing  is i have 12 dropdown . I Cant map all id`s to my grid . HAVE TO CHANGE ALOT .

ANy other solution avaiable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FindByText of dropdown items i.e.

```
ddlconfemail.SelectedValue = ddlconfemail.Items.FindByText(item["scoreconfirmeemail"].Text).Value;
```

Hope this will help you.